# Finding most frequent element in an array which occurs at least 3 times

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a code to print out the most frequent number in a **fixed sized** **array of 4** with an occurrence of **at least 3 times**.

For example:

```
int arr[4] = {9,2,9,9}
Number that occurs at least 3 times is: 9

int arr[4] = {9,9,9,9}
Number that occurs at least 3 times is: 9

int arr[4] = {-1,3,3,3}
Number that occurs at least 3 times is: 3

int arr[4] = {9,-1,9,9}
Number that occurs at least 3 times is: 9

int arr[4] = {1,1,2,2}
Number that occurs at least 3 times is: None
```

I tried:

```
int arr[4] = {9,2,9,9};
int i;
int count;
int value;
int first;

int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
int count = 0;
for (i=1;i<length-1;i++) {
    first = arr[0];
    if (first == arr[i]) {
        value = arr[i];
        count +=1;
    }
}
if (count >= 3) {
    printf("Number that occurs at least 3 times is: %d",value);
}
else {
    printf("Number that occurs at least 3 times is: None");
}
```

But I'm getting the output:

```
Number that occurs at least 3 times is: None
```

which supposed to be:

```
Number that occurs at least 3 times is: 9
```

What am i missing out? Would appreciate some assistance on this.

Comment: Run you code under debugger and look for yourself. I hope you are using a decent IDE.

Comment: or even gdb....

Comment: because of `for (i=1;i<length-1;i++)` you don't examine the last element. But your logic doesn't work anyway. What if `arr[0]` doesn't contain the most frequent number?

Comment: there are no complicated bugs here (heap corrupt, UB, stack corrupt,...), your code is doing exactly what you tell it to do. Debugging it yourself will be huge benefit to you in the future. If you cannot use a debugger, learn to.If you cannot then use a pencil and paper adn write down the values of all yr variables as you walk through the code in your head

Comment: you need to step away from the keyboard and think ... then you will realize you need to create a datastructure which holds each number you encounter as its key with its value a count of number of occurrences of that key ... with this approach you only need one iteration across your input array ... for each element of input array increment the matching key's value in your associative array datastructure ... while doing this you have an answer variable which keeps track of the largest found so far ... solution will be order N

Comment: How well would your code handle `int arr[] = { 8, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 8 };`?  I think it would likely report `8` (when other issues are fixed), but `1` appears four times whereas `8` only appears thrice.  Your algorithm is fundamentally flawed; you will need to start over and rethink how you are calculating the most frequent value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to fix your loop to compare also the last element:

```
for (i=1;i<length;i++) {
    ...
}
```

But if this doesn't find an element, it is possible that the first element does not contain the most frequent number, but the other three do. So you have to check, if the other three numbers are identical:

```
if (count >= 3) {
    printf("Number that occurs at least 3 times is: %d",value);
} else if (arr[1] == arr[2] && arr[1] == arr[3])
    printf("Number that occurs at least 3 times is: %d",arr[1]);
} else {
    printf("Number that occurs at least 3 times is: None");
}
```

This should cover all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Because your for loop runs only 2 times and count can at most be 2.